# Direct Access on Server 2k8 R2 Core

Tags: windows, vpn

Is it possible to install Direct Access on a Server Core instance? I've tried looking through oclist and dism but to no avail.

Using a GUI instance just for DA would be a waste of resources IMHO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not specifically listed as a supported role or feature on the Server Core page, it's not supported. DA isn't listed so, no go. There are several rather slim roles that aren't supported that really bothers me but, such is life. go full version.

Needless to say, with some patience there are a great deal of things you could get working on a Server Core even if it's not supported, [like all the parts of Exchange 2007](http://www.nullsession.com/2009/12/07/exch2k7-complete-install-on-windows-server-2008-r2-core/)... but I'd only do that in a lab for fun.

Answer (score -2):

What do you need it for?

You could use SSH instead

The requirements for DirectAccess are here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637797%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Half of our employees work at remote locations, and we need them to be able to access our infrastructure at any time. They all equipped with Windows 7 workstations.

SSH isn't really an option here, because it usually requires some steps to be executed by the users. The requirement page doesn't help me in any way

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with DirectAccess? 

If you need to issue remote commands to control your server, you can use:

1) PSExec from SysInternals suite:
2) WSH Remote Scripting
3) WinRM
4) Windows PowerShell 2.0 Remoting